# mysql query issue

Tags: mysql, join

Let's assume I have the below table

```
mysql> desc countrylist;  
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+  
| Field   | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |  
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+  
| country | varchar(32) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |  
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+  
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

While querying the table, I always want 'USA' in the result whether or not the value is there in the table, in addition to other countries in the table. How do I handle that?

TIA.

James.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just make sure that 'USA' is in the table?  If it's not there, put it back.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html):

```
SELECT country FROM countrylist
UNION
SELECT 'USA'
```

Comment: but its be twice in some cases ?

Comment: @haim evgi: The default behavior for UNION is that duplicate rows are removed from the result.

Comment: Btw, is there a way to do it without a Union? Using a single SELECT statement?